# Make image and text as default

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a little trouble by giving a appropriate title for this, so please correct me with your input.

Tapping in to my question (I have added a picture for clarification) When I click on button 1 a picture will show up to the left and a text will show up in the middle. If a click on button 2 a new picture will show up to the left and a new text will show up in the middle.

So my question is: How to I set button 1 as default so the picture and text connected with that button will show up when the website is loaded. Im new to JS so please explain by detail. Thanks. [![

```js
function changeText(value) {
  var div = document.getElementById("div");
  var text = "";
  var image = "";

  if (value == 1) text += "<span class='custom_text_h_w'>this is picture one</span> <br> <img class='custom_h_w' src='images/consumers_1.png'/>";
  if (value == 2) text += "<span class='custom_text_h_w'>this is picture two</span> <br> <img class='custom_h_w' src='images/consumers_2.png'/>";
  if (value == 3) text += "<span class='custom_text_h_w'>this is picture tree</span> <br> <img class='custom_h_w'src='images/consumers_3.png'/>";

  div.innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
.custom_h_w{
  top: 1700px;
  left: 100px;
  height:456px;
  width: 342px;
  position: absolute;
}

.custom_text_h_w{
  top: 1700px;
  right: 800px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript: changeText(1);">
   <img id="searchconsumers" src="images/search.png" width="60px" height="60px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(2);">
   <img id="exploreconsumers" src="images/explore.png" width="60px" height="60px" top="1700px" right="700px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(3);">
   <img id="funconsumers" src="images/fun.png" width="60px" height="60px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<div id="div"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can start the JavaScript function with the page with an HTML body tag like this:

```
<body onload="changeText(1);">
```

Alternatively, you can use JavaScript to do the same thing:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    changeText(1);
}
```

The 'DOMContentLoaded' event will trigger when the page is completely done loading in the user's browser.

Comment: <body onload="changeText(1);"> screwed up some of my other codes and document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    changeText(1);
} did the same. Do you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment ( not enought rep) but if i understand your problem right, you just wanna show your "text1" and "picture1" everytime you load the website, am i right?

if so, i have another question. Is your code working and doing exacly what you want except my question number one?

if Yes to both, just put your text1 and picture1 on your div, and then use JS to change the values or you text"content" and picture url

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Yes I can say yes to both. If I put it on my div and I click button 2 (to show picture 2 and text2) will it still change then?

Comment: glad i could help ;)

Comment: Stille have some problems. Can you try to make an example for me with the div?

Comment: what kind of problems are u getting now?

Answer (score 0):

You could give your pictures link `a` an identifier then on `DOMContentLoaded` click on the first one to show the `picture1` and `text1`, using `document.querySelector('#p_1').click();` check the example below.

**NOTE :** If you don't want to add extra identifiers in your code you could select frist anchor directly usisng :

```
document.querySelectorAll('a')[0].click();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  document.querySelector('#p_1').click();
})

function changeText(value) {
  var div = document.getElementById("div");
  var text = "";
  var image = "";

  if (value == 1) text += "<span class='custom_text_h_w'>this is picture one</span> <br> <img class='custom_h_w' src='http://www.xerys.com/images/xerys/1.png'/>";
  if (value == 2) text += "<span class='custom_text_h_w'>this is picture two</span> <br> <img class='custom_h_w' src='http://www.xerys.com/images/xerys/2.png'/>";
  if (value == 3) text += "<span class='custom_text_h_w'>this is picture tree</span> <br> <img class='custom_h_w' src='http://www.xerys.com/images/xerys/3.png'/>";

  div.innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
.custom_h_w{
  top: 120px;
  left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.custom_text_h_w{
  top: 70px;
  right: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript: changeText(1);" id="p_1">
   <img id="searchconsumers" src="images/search.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(2);" id="p_2">
   <img id="exploreconsumers" src="images/explore.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<a href="javascript: changeText(3);" id="p_3">
   <img id="funconsumers" src="images/fun.png" width="40px" height="40px" alt="abc" />
</a>
<div id="div"></div>
```